# CTE “Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part”

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I know this question has already been answered a lot, but I can't find the mistake.

I'm getting the following error:

> Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "Parent" of recursive query "GroupHierarchy".

This is the query:

```
WITH GroupHierarchy (UserGroupName, UserGroupID, IsGroup, Parent, Level)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
SELECT ug.UserGroupName, ug.UserGroupID, ug.IsGroup, CAST('' as nvarchar(MAX)) as Parent, 0 AS Level
FROM KnowledgeVaultMaster.dbo.UserGroup AS ug
WHERE ug.IsGroup = 0
UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
SELECT ug.UserGroupName, ug.UserGroupID, ug.IsGroup, CAST(gh.UserGroupName as nvarchar(MAX)) as Parent, Level + 1
FROM KnowledgeVaultMaster.dbo.UserGroup AS ug
JOIN KnowledgeVaultMaster.dbo.UserGroupGroup AS ugg
    ON ug.UserGroupID = ugg.ParentUserGroupId
INNER JOIN GroupHierarchy gh
    ON ugg.UserGroupId = gh.UserGroupID
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT UserGroupName, UserGroupID, IsGroup, Parent, Level
FROM GroupHierarchy
```

The original column `UserGroup.UserGroupName` is `nvarchar(255), not null`

EDIT: These are the tables (constraints and defaults omitted):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserGroup](
    [UserGroupID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserGroupName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [SystemName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [UserPassword] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Salt] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [IsGroup] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [SuperUser] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CreateUserID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [AuthType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserGroupGroup](
    [UserGroupId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ParentUserGroupId] [bigint] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] GO
```

Comment: So why cast it as max? Why not nvarchar(255)? Just wondering.

Comment: I don't know why are you getting that error, seems ok to me. But I believe you have mistakes in the logic of query. You will fall in endless loop

Comment: @uzi It should terminate when it runs out of parents if there are no loops

Comment: Shouldn't perhaps the first predicate in the recursive part be `ON ug.ParentUserGroupID = ugg.UserGroupId` instead of `ON ug.UserGroupID = ugg.ParentUserGroupId`?

Comment: Is this the actual query or have you "simplified" it? If the latter, I suspect you've removed vital details that mean the error isn't present now. If the former, I'm not seeing how the error is manifesting. I.e. if this is the actual query, it's unclear on why you're doing any type transformation.

Comment: @scsimon I already tried nvarchar(255) but it produced the exact same error.

Comment: @MK_ The hierarchy is bottom to top as table UserGroupGroup only contains relation to the parent (I should maybe invert the query after fixing the cast problem).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever No this is exactly the query I executed

Comment: No repro - I C&P this query into a new SSMS window, I create two tables with random column definitions which have names matching your tables and the query executes without error.

Comment: The column `Parent` of the cte is displayed as `nvarchar, null` in intelli sense whereas the original column `UserGroupName` is `nvarchar, not null`. Could this be an issue?

Comment: Yes @Matthias I would expect you to, but why the wasted space

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I also couldn't reproduce it with newly created tables from above script.
Is this some kind of compatibility problem? The original tables were imported as db with compatibility level `SQL Server 2012 (110)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. The database was imported with compatibility level `SQL Server 2012 (110)`.

I changed it to `SQL Server 2016 (130)` and now the cte works.